# Sublime text 3 при сохранении документа выполнить действие?

Tags: html, sublime-text-3

Приветствую жаждущих к познанию,
Вопрос:
Есть такая команда в Sublime text3
{
"keys": ["ctrl+shift+c"],
"command": "htmlprettify"
},
Выравнивает код в файле, можно ли ее как то переписать что бы она работала при сохранении документа ? может кто сталкивался подскажите пжл. спс.

Comment: Вот тут предлагают создать макрос из двух команд https://stackoverflow.com/a/23651124

Comment: Спасибо помогли, очень толковое решение.